# Prove $\frac{|a+b|}{1+|a+b|}<\frac{|a|}{1+|a|}+\frac{|b|}{1+|b|}$.

Tags: calculus, inequality

Prove that for every $a, b\in R\setminus\{0\}$ is correct this inequality:

$$\frac{|a+b|}{1+|a+b|}<\frac{|a|}{1+|a|}+\frac{|b|}{1+|b|}.$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function

$f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x}$,   $(x>0)$

is monotonically increasing because

$f'(x)=\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}>0$,

therefore by

$|a+b|<|a|+|b|$

have:

$f(|a+b|)<f(|a|+|b|)$

$\frac{|a+b|}{1+|a+b|}<\frac{|a|+|b|}{1+|a|+|b|}$=$\frac{|a|}{1+|a|+|b|}+\frac{|b|}{1+|a|+|b|}$<$\frac{|a|}{1+|a|}+\frac{|b|}{1+|b|}$.

Comment: I have never heard the term "breeders" before. Does it mean increasing?

Comment: What is breeders?

Comment: i would rather prefer the term "monotonically increasing".

Comment: The last expression is not the RHS of the desired inequality.

Answer (score 2):

**I. General case:**  Let $m,n$ and $p$ be positive real numbers and $m \leq n+p$. Let's prove that:

$$\frac{m}{1+m} \leq \frac{n}{1+n}+\frac{p}{1+p},$$

This inequality is equivalent to : 
$$m(1+m)(1+n) \leq n(1+p)(1+m)+p(1+n)(1+m) \Leftrightarrow$$ 
$$m+mn+mp \leq n+np+nm+p+pm+pn+mpn \Leftrightarrow$$
$$m \leq n+p+2np+mnp,$$ which it is true because $m \leq n+p$ and $m,n,p \in \mathbb{R_{+}}$.

**II. The inequality:**  We know that $\|a+b\| \leq \|a\|+\|b\|$ and so we take: 
\begin{eqnarray}
m&=&\|a+b\| \\
n&=&\|a\|\\
p&=&\|b\|,
\end{eqnarray}
because $\|a+b\|, \|a\|, \|b\| \in \mathbb{R_{+}}.$

The inequality is strict if $m\neq 0 \neq n\neq 0 \neq p$.