# Proof for inequality with absolute values: $\frac{|x+y|}{1+|x+y|} \leq \frac{|x|}{1+|x|} + \frac{|y|}{1+|y|}$

Tags: functions, inequality, absolute-value

If $x$ and $y$ are two real numbers then

$$\dfrac{|x+y|}{1+|x+y|} \leq \dfrac{|x|}{1+|x|} + \dfrac{|y|}{1+|y|}$$

How to prove above relation?

Comment: you just have many cases to check, actually there is an easier way, are you aware of the triangle inequality?

Comment: Also, this is easier if you note that $\frac{z}{1+z}=1-\frac{1}{1+z}$.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of triangle inequality and it's proof.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove $\frac{|a+b|}{1+|a+b|}&lt;\frac{|a|}{1+|a|}+\frac{|b|}{1+|b|}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194314/prove-fracab1ab-fraca1a-fracb1b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{|x|}{1+|x|}+\frac{|y|}{1+|y|}\geq\frac{|x|}{1+|x|+|y|}+\frac{|y|}{1+|x|+|y|}=$$
$$=\frac{|x|+|y|}{1+|x|+|y|}=1-\frac{1}{1+|x|+|y|}\geq1-\frac{1}{1+|x+y|}=\frac{|x+y|}{1+|x+y|}.$$

Comment: How are you able to conclude the last step (it needs some more effort). The denominator has increased!!!

Comment: @Anurag A I fixed. Se now please.

Comment: (+1) yes it is fixed now, that what I was thinking about.

Comment: As an intermediate learner, I am comparing your answer with another to the duplicate question. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3462696/inequality-with-absolue-value

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

Let $f(t)=\frac{t}{1+t}$ for $t \geq 0$. Then 
$$f^{'}(t)=\frac{1}{(1+t)^2} > 0 \qquad \forall t \geq 0.$$
Thus $f$ is an increasing function.

Now show that 
$$f(a+b) \leq f(a)+f(b) \qquad \forall a,b \geq 0.$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(t) = {\large{\frac{t}{1+t}}}$.

Then $f(t) = 1- {\large{\frac{1}{1+t}}}$, hence $f$ is increasing on $[0,\infty)$.

It follows that the LHS of the inequality doesn't get smaller if $x,y$ are replaced by $|x|,|y|$.

And clearly, if $x,y$ are replaced by $|x|,|y|$, the RHS stays the same.

Thus, it suffices to consider the case $x,y \ge 0$, since the truth of the inequality for that case implies the truth for the others.

But then, assuming $x,y \ge 0$, we have
\begin{align*}
&\,\frac{|x|}{1+|x|} + \frac{|y|}{1+|y|}-\frac{|x+y|}{1+|x+y|}\\[6pt] 
=&\;f(x)+f(y)-f(x+y)\\[6pt]
=&\;\frac{(xy)(2+x+y)}{(1+x)(1+y)(1+x+y)}
\qquad\text{(identically)}\\[6pt]
\end{align*}
which is obviously nonnegative.