# Given $|b-c|\leq a\leq b+c$ show that $\frac{a}{1+a}\leq\frac{b}{1+b}+\frac{c}{1+c}$

Tags: inequality, triangle-inequality

I am trying to show the following:

> Given that $|b-c| \leq a \leq b+c$ show that:
> $$\frac{a}{1+a} \leq \frac{b}{1+b} + \frac{c}{1+c}$$

So far I have done the following:

$a/(1+a) \leq b/(1+b) + c/(1+c) \iff$

$1-1/(1+a) \leq 2 - 1/(1+b) -1/(1+c) \iff$

$1/(1+b) -1/(1+c) \leq 1 + 1/(1+a) \iff$

$ (2+b+c)/(1+b)(1+c) \leq (2+a)/(1+a) \iff$

$ (2+b+c)(1+a) \leq (2+a)(1+b)(1+c) \iff$

$ a \leq bc(2+a)$

I am not really sure how to proceed from here- any help or hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/194314/42969  and some more – all found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac%7Bx%7D%7B1%2Bx%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7By%7D%7B1%2By%7D%5Cge%5Cfrac%7Bz%7D%7B1%2Bz%7D%24).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume that $a,b,c > 0$ because without such an assumption we cannot even have $1+b$ and $1+c$ in the denominator.

$f(x)=\frac x {1+x}$ is an increasing function of $x$ on $[0,\infty)$. Hence $\frac a {1+a} \leq \frac {b+c} {1+b+c} =\frac b {1+b+c}+\frac c {1+b+c} \leq \frac b {1+b} +\frac c {1+c} $.

Comment: This has probably been asked and answered more than a dozen times ...

Answer (score 0):

I suppose $b,c\ge0$.
$$
\frac{b}{1 + b} + \frac{c}{1 + c} \ge \frac{a}{1 + a}
$$
$$
\Rightarrow \frac{b + c + 2bc}{1 + b + c +bc} \ge \frac{a}{1 + a}
$$
$$
\Rightarrow  b + c + 2bc + ab +ca + 2abc\ge a + ab + ca + abc
$$
$$
\Rightarrow b + c + 2bc + abc \ge a
$$
Add
$$
b + c \ge a \quad \textrm{and} \quad bc(a +2)\ge0
$$
And we are done.